# Stacked bar plot in different colors in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, colormap

I have two issues with a code (see below).

1) I have two bars and I would like each bar two be coloured with a different colormap (GnBu for 'male' and RdPu for 'female'). I tried creating a list 'colors' including the two colormaps, but it didn't work very well.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(([[3.31, 3.19, 10.17, 7.69, 8.00, 20.83, 16.25, 30.00, 10.00, 38.00], [3.34, 5.13, 5.21, 4.56, 8.94, 7.75, 3.82, 1.75, 0, 0]]), columns=['18-24','25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65-70'], index=['male','female'])
color1 = plt.cm.GnBu(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
color2 = plt.cm.RdPu(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
colors=(color1,color2)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width = 0.99, figsize=(10, 42), color=colors, rot=0)
plt.ylabel('history (years)')
```

2) If I have a second, third... dataset e.g.

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.abs([[3.71,3.29,2.59,3.06,2.57,2.70,5.50,2.25,2.00,2.50], [2.59,2.50,2.38,2.19,3.20,3.00,2.25,7.00,0,0]]), columns=['18-24','25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65-70'], index=['male','female'])`

and I want to plot it within the same figure, but with some space to the first two bars..., would be grateful for a hint. Bars should always be paired ('male' and 'female').

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your code.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to achieve... maybe you can sketch up something and upload it so we know what your plot should look like in the end?

Comment: 1) I provided a code, which generates two stacked bars. I would like the first bar ('male') to be colored with a colormap GnBU and the second one ('female') with RdPu.

Comment: 2) Also,I would like to add more such bar pairs to the plot (I provided another dataset). Between each pair there should be little empty space, so one can recognize which two bars belong together. Sorry for the confusion, hope it's clear now...

Answer (score 0):

[Stacked Bar Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym8G5.png)

Try the below code :-

```
N = 3
top_sector = (914,300, 200) ## No of Investment in top sectors for C1/C2/C3
second_sector = (770,200,100) ## No of Investment in 2nd highest sector for C1/C2/C3
third_sector = (282,100,50) ## No of Investment in 3rd highest sector for C1/C2/C3
# fourth_sector = (0,0,0)`enter code here`
# fifth_sector = (0,0,0)`enter code here`
ind = np.arange(N)`enter code here`
width = 0.35

p1 = plt.bar(ind,top_sector,width,color=['blue'])
p2 = plt.bar(ind,second_sector,width,color=['red'])
p3 = plt.bar(ind,third_sector,width,color=['green'])`enter code here`
# p4 = plt.bar(ind,top_sector,width,color=['yellow'])`enter code here`
# p5 = plt.bar(ind,top_sector,width,color=['purple'])

    plt.xlabel('Top 3 Countries for Investment')

plt.ylabel('No of Investment (Count)')
plt.title('No of Investment in top 3 sectors of top 3 countries')
plt.xticks(ind,('USA' , 'GBR', 'IND'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1000,200))`enter code here`
plt.legend((p1[0],p2[0],p3[0],p4[0],p5[0]),('Others',' Health', 'Entertainment', 'Cleantech / Semiconductors','News,Searching/Msg'))
plt.show()
```